# Accessing data in RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

Im new to C# and in VB i could do the following:

```
Protected Sub DataGrid1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemCommand
        If e.CommandName = "CommandName" Then

            Dim label1 As Label = e.Item.FindControl("label1")

            Response.Write(label1.Text))


        End If

    End Sub
```

in C# and the RowCommand, I cannot use findcontrol to access a controls value.  I want to get the value of two label's so I can use them when I call a method in the rowcommand

**Update:**
In C# when I do

```
Label label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("label1");
```

or

```
Label label1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("label1");
```

I do not have Row or Item available

Comment: Are you handling the same event in C# as you are in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a CommandArgument in the button and was able to get what I needed:

.aspx in the gridview

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnActive" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' CommandName='<%# Eval("Activity")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Activity")%>' runat="server" />
```

then in the RowCammand in the .aspx.cs

```
  protected void gridview_RowCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.CommandName == "Disable")
                    {
                          string[] args = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
                          Guid gArticleId = new Guid(args[0]);

                          Response.Write(gArticleId);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does Label1 exist?  Could you post your C# example?  It should also be DataGridCommandEventArgs type, so maybe it's a different argument?  I don't see, as the same event arg type, how Item couldn't exist.  It's hard to tell without seeing the full C# example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
        OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand"
        >
    <columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblArticleId" Text='<%# Eval("Id")%>' Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnActive" CommandName='<%# Eval("Activity")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Activity")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs:

```
protected void gridView_RowCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "Disable") 
                {
                    UpdateArticleVisibility(true, [lblArticleID.Text value], gOrgId);
                }

                if (e.CommandName == "Enable")
                {
                    UpdateArticleVisibility(false, [lblArticleID.Text value], gOrgId);
                }
            }
```